# Itegrating django-disqus on a https site

Tags: python, django, disqus

I'm using the django-disqus package (https://github.com/arthurk/django-disqus) on my web site which works great in dev.  However my production server is running on https and when I view the page I get an error and the disqus comments are not loaded.  The error shown in the console states that the code is blocked as it is trying to run insecure content from ...discus.com/count.js and ...discus.com/embed.js and the content should be loaded over HTTPS.

Does anyone know how I can solve this?  I've had a look at the docs http://django-disqus.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ but cant find this mentioned.

Comment: So use HTTPS to serve these JS files - what's stopping you?

Comment: I just wanted to know if there was a setting for the Django-Disqus package which you changed rather than having to hack the code in order to get it to work

Comment: I've just opened an issue for this - https://github.com/arthurk/django-disqus/issues/33 - for now you have to change it on your own.

Comment: There's already been an issue opened on this since 2012.

Comment: The project seems to be dead.

Comment: Anyone that's interested.  I've contacted the repository owner and gotten access to the project on github.  I've merged in a branch the supports protocol relative URLs.  You can install this by using pip 

```pip install git+https://github.com/arthurk/django-disqus```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Edit 2 (July 15, 2014):

The newest release of django-disqus has been uploaded to pypi and can be installed through pip or easy_install.  This includes templates that use protocol relative urls, so it may now be easily used on sites served from HTTP or HTTPS.

## Edit (July 4, 2014):

I've contacted the repository owner and gotten access.  The latest merge into master supports protocol relative urls.  It can be installed directly from github using pip:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/arthurk/django-disqus
```

## Original Answer:

Just taking a quick look at the code for django-disqus on github

https://github.com/arthurk/django-disqus/blob/master/disqus/templates/disqus/show_comments.html

It looks like the http protocol is being hard-coded.  There is already an open issue on github to support this, however it doesn't look like the code has been touched for a while, which means the author probably isn't interested (also, there are 10 open pull requests, which isn't a great sign either).

https://github.com/arthurk/django-disqus/issues/18

### Your easiest solution is this:

In your settings.py file, make sure your template configuration is something like this (I do this on all my projects, so I can easily override the templates in some 3rd party apps, by providing an alternative template in my site:

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join('path', 'to', 'mydjangoroot', 'myprojectroot', 'templates'),)
```

Find the django-disqus package on your machine and copy the 'templates' folder, into the same folder as your settings.py file (if you do something like what I've displayed above)

If you just want to use HTTPS, it's a simple matter of opening the template files modifying the protocol used from HTTP to HTTPS.

### Why this works

When do you something like call one of the functions that renders a template, (like django.shortcuts.render).

Django uses a series of template loader classes to figure out where exactly your template is located.

The **filesystem.Loader**, that I have specified first, will first use any directories I have listed in the tuple assigned to TEMPLATE_DIRS.

Second, if the template wasn't found the **app_directories.Loader**, it will search any of the installed apps, under a subdirectory called 'templates' for a path matching the template requests.  This is usually the behavior I prefer, so, as I mentioned above, I can override the templates for a 3rd party app directly from within my project.